# Can my company see that i'm using SSH?

Tags: ssh, proxy

In my company we use our own notebooks.

Due to web filters, I decided to create an SSH tunnel to use my home internet connection.

My question is: can my company identify that I'm using SSH? I've configured Firefox to connect to my SSH tunnel via SOCKS v5 and I'm using Bitvise SSH.

I ask because I think they might block all SSH connections, to avoid high bandwidth usage.

Comment: Yes they can.  SSH is a very recognizable protocol.

Comment: Even if i'm using it at a different port?

Comment: @LucasMaffazioli Yes. Just by using simple tools such as Wireshark, you can easily identify SSH traffic, regardless of which port are you using.

Comment: you could use http tunnelling to make it look like regular http

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Absolutely; they can see every packet going across their network, and analyse and block it as required.

They should draw up a detailed acceptable use policy if they're going to make you use your own machine for work. Check if there is one. If they haven't told you not to tunnel personal traffic back home then they can't really complain if you do it!

Comment: There are several tools to obfuscate ssh traffic, however it's likely only good to defend against automated analysis.